# Problem with fetching API with user input

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a search form where you can search for a city/country. I'm getting a response, but it adds localhost to the url

> http://localhost:3000/api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=london&username=username

Which it shouldn't do... What I'm I doing wrong?

```
state = {
            text: ""
          }



 handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }



componentDidMount() {
    const endpoint = `${api}q=${this.state.text}&username=${userName}`
    console.log(endpoint)
    fetch(endpoint)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }



handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({text: ""})

    this.componentDidMount()

  }



 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>CityPop</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h3>Search by city</h3>
          <input
            type="search"
            name="text"
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button>Search city</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: You don't show how `api` is set.

Comment: I'm getting it from another file where I declared the api url to a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `http/https` protocol before the link:

```
const endpoint = `https://${api}q=${this.state.text}&username=${userName}`;
```